# Add specific files to squid cache

Tags: squid

I have set up squid-deb-proxy on Ubuntu, but would like to be able to add packages downloaded on other networks (e.g. McDonald's or college WiFi) to the cache. I have asked a question specific to squid-deb-proxy [here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/111892/8724), but thought maybe the good folks here at Super User would be able to help me if I just tried to work with squid.

In a nutshell, is there a way to add specific files to the squid cache? Instructions for Ubuntu are preferable.